# Change value of variable in subclass?

Tags: java, variables, subclass

I have 2 classes . The one is about a 24 hour clock and the second one is a subclass of the first and is a 12 hour clock.
To convert the new time in second class i need to change the value of the first class. But i can't do that. 
I am talking about "h" variable
Specifically...

```
    class Clock{
    public int h, m , s;
    public String a,b,c;

    public void setHour(int hour){
        this.h = hour;
    }
    public void setMin(int min){
        this.m = min;
    }
    public void setSec(int sec){
        this.s = sec;
    }
    public void tick(){ 
        if(h != 23){
            if(m == 59 && s==59){
                m = 0;
                s=0;
                h++;
            }
            else if(m != 59 && s == 59){
                m++;
                s=0;
            }
            else if ( m != 59 && s != 59){
                s++;
            }
            else if( m == 59 && s!=59){
                s++;
            }
        }

        else if(h == 23 && m == 59 && s !=59){
            s++;
        }
        else if(h == 23 && m!=59 && s == 59){
            s=0;
            s++;
            m++;
        }
        else if(h == 23 && m!=59 && s!=59){
            s++;
        } 
        else if(h == 23 && m == 59 && s == 59){
            s = 0;
            m =0;
            h = 0;
        }
    }
    public String toString(){ 
        a = "";
        b = "";
        c = "";

        if (h < 10)
            a = "0";
        if (m <10 )
            b = "0";
        if (s <10)
            c = "0";

        return a+h+":"+b+m+":"+c+s;
    }
}

   class AMPMClock extends Clock{
    Clock clock2 = new Clock();
    public void setAMPM(boolean yes){
        if(yes == true){
            **clock2.h = clock2.h - 12**;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to change the h variable if setAMPM is true. but i wont change!! It gives me 00:00:00

Comment: shouldn't the 24 hour clock an EXTENSION to the 12 hour clock?

Comment: You should re-design your inheritance structure: it is in severe violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), since a 12-hour clock is definitely *not* a 24-hour clock. You should have an abstract base class `Clock`, from which you derive both the 12-h and 24-h clock classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AMPMClock` should either just extend `Clock` or just use it. But you are trying to combine them both as follows:

```
class AMPMClock extends Clock {
    Clock clock2 = new Clock();
```

Either extend:

```
class AMPMClock extends Clock {
```

Because, the public accesor methods are inherited, you can invoke getter/setter methods on `this`. e.g. `this.getHour()`.

Or use it but don't extend:

```
class AMPMClock {
    Clock clock2 = new Clock();
```

Here, instead of `this` use `clock2`. e.g. `clock2.getHour()`.

But, you need to make all the instance members private (they should not to be public). And make corresponding public getter/setter for all of them.

As suggested by dasblinkenlight:

It would be better to have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseClock {
    private int h, m, s;
    //getter/setter
}
```

And two different concrete classes:

```
public class TwelveHourClock extends BaseClock { }
```

and

```
public class TwentyFourHourClock extends BaseClock { }
```

Comment: yes but what should i write in BaseClock ?? because in Clock class i have written the general code .. how to change it and write in different class the 24 hour clock??

Answer (score 1):

The tactical answer is to change click2 with "this". The strategic, bigger problem is that are not really utilizing inheritance properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write

```
class AMPMClock extends Clock {
  private boolean pm = false;
  public void setHour(int hour) {
    if (hour >= 12) {
        hour -= 12;
        pm = true;
    } else {
        pm = false;
    }
    super.setHour(hour);
  }
  public void setPM(boolean pm){
    this.pm = pm;
  }
}
```

The `hour` should be validated when it is set.  The fields should all be private and you should ahve getters for the hour, mins & secs. You don't need two Clocks in AMPMClock as AMPMClock is a Clock. Having a AM/PM set to `yes` is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting confused about the difference between classes and objects.

check out: http://www.codestyle.org/java/faq-Objects.shtml#classobjectdiff